# Defining onClick method in onCreate

Tags: android

I'm trying to define this onClick method in my onCreate activity

```
public void GetMusicListLock(View v) {

    Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class);
    final int resultLock=1;
    getNameScreenIntent.putExtra("Lock","LockScreen");
    startActivityForResult(getNameScreenIntent, resultLock);

}
```

but it gave me error saying "Cannot resolve symbol v".

It works just fine if I define the method outside of onCreate. I want to know if there's a way to define onClick method inside of onCreate.

Comment: you can't create method inside method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this in your onCreate:

```
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class);
        final int resultLock=1;
        getNameScreenIntent.putExtra("Lock","LockScreen");
        startActivityForResult(getNameScreenIntent, resultLock);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is for XML onClick

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXT"
    android:onClick="GetMusicListLock"/>
```

If you want to set it to a view you can try this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class);
            final int resultLock=1;
            getNameScreenIntent.putExtra("Lock","LockScreen");
            startActivityForResult(getNameScreenIntent, resultLock);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I assume that I need to define button1 first?